# String manipulaiton runtime error python

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error

Input: 3

```
gandhi
mahatma gandhI
Mohndas KaramChand gandhi
```

Output:

```
Gandhi 
M. Gandhi 
M. K. Gandhi
```

And I wrote the following code:

```
n =  int(input())


while n > 0  :
  k = raw_input()

  if k.find(" ") != -1:

    final = str(k[0].upper() + '.')


    for i in range(len(k)) :
      if (k[i] == ' ') & (k[i:].find(" ")):
        final += k[i+1].upper() + ". "
      else:
          if(k[i] == ' '):
            final += k[i+1].upper() + k[i+2:].lower()


    n -= 1

    print final[0:len(final)]

 else :
    print  k[0].upper() + k[1:].lower()
```

I'm getting a runtime error for this. Can someone explain why?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: What are the run time errors you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
str = "gandhi mahatma gandhi Mohndas KaramChand gandhi"
temp = ''
for st in str.split():
    if st == 'gandhi':
        temp = temp + ' ' + st.title()
    else:
        temp = temp + ' ' + st[0].upper() + '.'
print temp
```

Output as per your expectation - Gandhi M. Gandhi M. K. Gandhi